# How do I dump secret text files to the console?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I use this script to dump credentials in the script console:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.*
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.awscredentials.AWSCredentialsImpl
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.StringCredentials

def showRow = { credentialType, secretId, username = null, password = null, description = null ->
  println("${credentialType} : ".padLeft(20) + secretId?.padRight(38)+" | " +username?.padRight(20)+" | " +password?.padRight(40) + " | " +description)
}

domainName = null

credentialsStore = Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList('com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider')[0]?.getStore()
domain = new Domain(domainName, null, Collections.<DomainSpecification>emptyList())

credentialsStore?.getCredentials(domain).each{
  if(it instanceof UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl)
    showRow("user/password", it.id, it.username, it.password?.getPlainText(),it.description)
  else if(it instanceof BasicSSHUserPrivateKey)
    showRow("ssh priv key", it.id, it.passphrase?.getPlainText(), it.privateKeySource?.getPrivateKey(), it.description )
  else if(it instanceof AWSCredentialsImpl)
    showRow("aws", it.id, it.accessKey, it.secretKey?.getPlainText(),it.description )
  else if(it instanceof StringCredentials)
    showRow("secret text", it.id, it.secret?.getPlainText(), it.description, '' )
  else
    showRow("something else", it.id)
}

return
```

But it doesnt dump "Secret file" cred types (they fall through to "something else".

How can I also dump the contents of secret files in this script? What is the class for "Secret file"? what instanceof would that be?

Comment: What language is this?  Looks like Java?

Comment: the script console runs groovy

Comment: println it.dump()